# why N entries of HashMap and N entries of HashSet take same space in Heap?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset, jconsole

i am checking whether Set takes less memory than Map. 
because in Map we Enter 2 Integer objects but in Set we store (1 Integer) + (1 Static Object)

RUN 1:- 
i have tried to fill Set with 50,000 integers by testSet(i) function

RUN 2:-
i have tried to fill Map with 50,000 integers by testMap(i) function

and analyzed HeapMemory with Jconsole, both run shows 30-31MB of memory usage.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestSetMapSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int i = 50000;          
        //testSet(i);
        testMap(i);
    }

    private static void testMap(int i) throws InterruptedException {
        Map<Integer,Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>((int) Math.ceil(51000 / 0.75));

        while(i > 0) {
            m.put(new Integer(i), new Integer(i));
            System.out.println(i);
                Thread.sleep(1);
            i--;
        }

    }

    private static void testSet(int i) throws InterruptedException {

        Set<Integer> m = new HashSet<Integer>((int) Math.ceil(51000 / 0.75));

        while(i > 0) {
            m.add(new Integer(i));
            i--;
            System.out.println(i);
            Thread.sleep(1);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Because `HashSet` is backed by `HashMap`?

Comment: in map i am inserting 2*50k objects, but in set 50k + 1 dummy object. so space should not be same. @ANDY

Comment: Could be that your measurement is not exact. Try to do it with 5M objects each.

Answer (score 0):

From the JDK source code, you can see `HashSet` is using `HashMap` to store the values:

```
public class HashSet<E>
    extends AbstractSet<E>
    implements Set<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
    static final long serialVersionUID = -5024744406713321676L;

    private transient HashMap<E,Object> map;

    // Dummy value to associate with an Object in the backing Map
    private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();

    /**
     * Constructs a new, empty set; the backing <tt>HashMap</tt> instance has
     * default initial capacity (16) and load factor (0.75).
     */
    public HashSet() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new set containing the elements in the specified
     * collection.  The <tt>HashMap</tt> is created with default load factor
     * (0.75) and an initial capacity sufficient to contain the elements in
     * the specified collection.
     *
     * @param c the collection whose elements are to be placed into this set
     * @throws NullPointerException if the specified collection is null
     */
    public HashSet(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        map = new HashMap<>(Math.max((int) (c.size()/.75f) + 1, 16));
        addAll(c);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new, empty set; the backing <tt>HashMap</tt> instance has
     * the specified initial capacity and the specified load factor.
     *
     * @param      initialCapacity   the initial capacity of the hash map
     * @param      loadFactor        the load factor of the hash map
     * @throws     IllegalArgumentException if the initial capacity is less
     *             than zero, or if the load factor is nonpositive
     */
    public HashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
        map = new HashMap<>(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new, empty set; the backing <tt>HashMap</tt> instance has
     * the specified initial capacity and default load factor (0.75).
     *
     * @param      initialCapacity   the initial capacity of the hash table
     * @throws     IllegalArgumentException if the initial capacity is less
     *             than zero
     */
    public HashSet(int initialCapacity) {
        map = new HashMap<>(initialCapacity);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new, empty linked hash set.  (This package private
     * constructor is only used by LinkedHashSet.) The backing
     * HashMap instance is a LinkedHashMap with the specified initial
     * capacity and the specified load factor.
     *
     * @param      initialCapacity   the initial capacity of the hash map
     * @param      loadFactor        the load factor of the hash map
     * @param      dummy             ignored (distinguishes this
     *             constructor from other int, float constructor.)
     * @throws     IllegalArgumentException if the initial capacity is less
     *             than zero, or if the load factor is nonpositive
     */
    HashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean dummy) {
        map = new LinkedHashMap<>(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
    }

    /**
     * Returns an iterator over the elements in this set.  The elements
     * are returned in no particular order.
     *
     * @return an Iterator over the elements in this set
     * @see ConcurrentModificationException
     */
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return map.keySet().iterator();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in this set (its cardinality).
     *
     * @return the number of elements in this set (its cardinality)
     */
    public int size() {
        return map.size();
    }

    /**
     * Returns <tt>true</tt> if this set contains no elements.
     *
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if this set contains no elements
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return map.isEmpty();
    }

    /**
     * Returns <tt>true</tt> if this set contains the specified element.
     * More formally, returns <tt>true</tt> if and only if this set
     * contains an element <tt>e</tt> such that
     * <tt>(o==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;e==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;o.equals(e))</tt>.
     *
     * @param o element whose presence in this set is to be tested
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if this set contains the specified element
     */
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return map.containsKey(o);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present.
     * More formally, adds the specified element <tt>e</tt> to this set if
     * this set contains no element <tt>e2</tt> such that
     * <tt>(e==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;e2==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;e.equals(e2))</tt>.
     * If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set
     * unchanged and returns <tt>false</tt>.
     *
     * @param e element to be added to this set
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if this set did not already contain the specified
     * element
     */
    public boolean add(E e) {
        return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the specified element from this set if it is present.
     * More formally, removes an element <tt>e</tt> such that
     * <tt>(o==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;e==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;o.equals(e))</tt>,
     * if this set contains such an element.  Returns <tt>true</tt> if
     * this set contained the element (or equivalently, if this set
     * changed as a result of the call).  (This set will not contain the
     * element once the call returns.)
     *
     * @param o object to be removed from this set, if present
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if the set contained the specified element
     */
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return map.remove(o)==PRESENT;
    }

    /**
     * Removes all of the elements from this set.
     * The set will be empty after this call returns.
     */
    public void clear() {
        map.clear();
    }

...
```

A more detailed source code reference: https://github.com/pengisgood/jdk-source-code/blob/master/src/java/util/HashSet.java

By the way, the above link is the source code of JDK 8.

Comment: but as per implementation, Set inserts 1 Dummy Object in all value part. so space Should be saved i think.

Comment: @user3869979 I don't know how you measure it. The used space should not be the same exactly.

Comment: yha ... thats what i thought. but i measured heap area from jConsol. it was same or some time more in HashSet.